# How do I save the contents of TWebBrowser, including user-entered form values?

Tags: forms, delphi, save, twebbrowser

is it possible to save entire document loaded in Webbrowser (in Delphi) as a ordinary HTML file with new values (I mean values entered by user in html's forms this document)?
I need this for reading this HTML document with all values next time when application will be used.

Comment: If this was possible, the Delphi app could retrieve the form field values even before the user submits the HTML form. Including sensitive data such as passwords.

Comment: @mjn, well, but it is possible. You can pretty easily get original values that user entered even from masked input fields (like passwords). Don't know about saving to document, but I think you'll have to modify it by yourself when saving.

Comment: If this works with password type input fields, I would not trust any app which uses an embedded web browser to communicate with Internet sites,for example doing an OAuth login.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure this is possible!

Small demo App, make a new vcl forms application, drop a `TWebBrowser`, a `TButton` and a `TMemo` on your form and use this code (don't forget to bind `OnCreate` for the Form and `OnClick` for the Button)

```
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, OleCtrls, SHDocVw, StdCtrls,mshtml, ActiveX;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

//code snagged from about.com
procedure WBLoadHTML(WebBrowser: TWebBrowser; HTMLCode: string) ;
var
   sl: TStringList;
   ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
   WebBrowser.Navigate('about:blank') ;
   while WebBrowser.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;

   if Assigned(WebBrowser.Document) then
   begin
     sl := TStringList.Create;
     try
       ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
       try
         sl.Text := HTMLCode;
         sl.SaveToStream(ms) ;
         ms.Seek(0, 0) ;
         (WebBrowser.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(ms)) ;
       finally
         ms.Free;
       end;
     finally
       sl.Free;
     end;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  Doc : IHtmlDocument2;

begin
 Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHtmlDocument2;
 Memo1.Lines.Text := Doc.body.innerHTML;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

var
  Html : String;
begin
 Html := 'change value of input and press Button1 to changed DOM<br/><input id="myinput" type="text" value="orgval"></input>';
 WBLoadHTML(WebBrowser1, Html);
end;

end.
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**

As **mjn** pointed out, the values of **password** type inputs will not be shown.
You can still can get their value though:

add these 2 lines to Button1.Click and change html

OnCreate:

```
Html := 'change value of input and press Button1 to changed DOM<br/><input id="myinput" type="password" value="orgval"></input>';
```

OnClick:

```
El := (Doc as IHtmlDocument3).getElementById('myinput') as IHtmlInputElement;
     Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('value of password field = %s', [El.value]))
```

Comment: just curious: does this even work for password type input fields?

Comment: @mjn: see my edit, it is possible but it requires knowledge of the Html document, no generic solution in that case...

Comment: @mjn Why? Rather than IE consider an application that has a password field. That application needs to be able to get hold of the password.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, It is bad because my external application can read passwords from other IE application... not tested though. but I can defenetlly access foreign IE DOM from my own application, by the window handle, so mjn has a point here.

Comment: @kobik Once you install malware on your machine you are hosed. If your process can read the password, then the malware can just inject into your process and read it.